# Consuming Web Services On Iphone

Tags: iphone, web-services

This probably sounds like a really dumb question, but here goes....Web Services, what the hell are they and how do I find what web services are available for me to develop with?

Ive searched Google for a tutorial or a list of Web Services but I dont seem to be able to find either a reasonable definition or how to go about implementing them.

Any help or links to helpful tutorials or books is, as always greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not going to be one big list of web services. Generally, you figure out what you want your app to do, and go looking for APIs based on that.

If you wanted to write something that hooked into Twitter, you'd have it hook into Twitter's API. If you wanted to show the user a list of nearby locations, you might hook into FourSquare's API.

Comment: Thanks :) In 2 sentences you've done what a day searching with google couldnt. At least now I know where to start looking and it was the nearest locations, I was trying to implement but had no idea where to look. Again, many thanks.

Comment: I found this site when searching for something to do with a website Im currently building: http://www.programmableweb.com/ Is this a list of the sort of things I could use?

Comment: That's a list, certainly. No list will be complete, and you'd be best off figuring out what you want to do first and look for APIs second.

Answer (score 0):

Web service is nothing much. It is just a web application developed that would specially returned something in a special predefined format. So that other software can use it.